# How to intercept error when expect fails? Jasmine and frisby

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jasmine

I am creating HTTP tests with frisby.js which works on top of jasmine.js.

I also have to create some mongoDB objects to test against. 
The problem is when I want to clean up these DB objects. When one of the expects fail I want to intercept that and call my own cleanup function. This means that after each failed test, I won't be able to remove the test objects from the DB.

The afterEach function in jasmine does not work properly and jasmine does not have any support for afterAll or beforeAll yet. 
That is why I have made the tests as they are today.

```
it("testing userform get with correct userID and expect correct return", function() {
    var innerUserId = userID;
    frisby.create('Should retrieve correct userform and return 200 when using a valid userID')
        .get(url.urlify('/api/userform', {id: innerUserId}))
        .expectStatus(200)
        .afterJSON(function(userform){
            // If any of these fail, the after function wont run.
            // I want to intercept the error so that I can make sure that the cleanUp function is called
            // afterEach does not work. I have tried with done()
            var useridJSON = userform.UserId.valueOf();
            var firstnameJSON = userform.firstname.valueOf();
            var surnameJSON = userform.surname.valueOf();
            expect(firstnameJSON).toMatch(testUser.firstName);
            expect(surnameJSON).toMatch(testUser.surname);
            expect(useridJSON).toMatch(innerUserId);
        })
        .after(function(){
            cleanUp(innerUserId);
        })
        .toss();
});
```

I am wondering if there is a way to intercept the error for "expect" in frisby or jasmine so that I can make a call to my own cleanup function before exiting.

Full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6w8j7u2x/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution to this problem is to wrap the error code in a try-catch. 
This is because if a javascript error occurs, jasmine will NOT keep running assertions. This is different from an assertion error. If an assertion error occurs, jasmine and frisby will keep on testing all the other assertions and then do the "after"-function.

```
        .afterJSON(function(userform){
            try {
              var useridJSON = userform.UserId.valueOf();
              var firstnameJSON = userform.firstname.valueOf();
              var surnameJSON = userform.surname.valueOf();
            catch(e) {
               cleanUp(innerUserId);
               // Can do a throw(e.message); here aswell
            }
            expect(firstnameJSON).toMatch(testUser.firstName);
            expect(surnameJSON).toMatch(testUser.surname);
            expect(useridJSON).toMatch(innerUserId);
        })
```

This is not the pretty way, but works.

I ended up adding the throw(e) and placed the expects in a finally scope. This way I got jasmine to present all the errors that occured in the test.

Answer (score 0):

As for "before exiting", how about this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.error(' Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

Comment: Does not work because jasmine does not throw an exception if an expect fails. I could add .toThrow() to all of my expect, but I am wondering if it is a not so "filthy" way of handeling this.